# Iterate with a button to a certain value in the Bokeh graph

Tags: python, matlab, plot, graph, bokeh

The following code creates the following graph

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import Button, CustomJS
from bokeh.layouts import row
from random import random

p = figure(x_range=(0, 10))
p.line(list(range(1000)), [random() for _ in range(1000)])

b = Button(label='Show next 10', callback=CustomJS(args=dict(xr=p.x_range), 
code="""
 xr.start = xr.end;
 xr.end = xr.end + 10;
"""))
```

Instead of showing the next 10 on the graph, how can I make it show the next value of '0.5' from the y-axis compared to the current position

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `random` with `choice` since finding a particular value in an array of random float values will almost always return nothing.

This code scrolls current viewport in such a way so that the next suitable value is exactly in the middle. When there's no such value, pressing the button won't do anything.

Note that all this talk about "next values" implies that the data for x-axis is not decreasing at any step.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import Button, CustomJS, ColumnDataSource
from random import choice

p = figure(x_range=(0, 10))
ds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=list(range(1000)),
                                y=[choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) for _ in range(1000)]))
p.line(x='x', y='y', source=ds)

TARGET_Y = 2

b = Button(label='Show next {}'.format(TARGET_Y),
           callback=CustomJS(args=dict(ds=ds, xr=p.x_range),
                             code="""
    const half_span = (xr.end - xr.start) / 2;
    const mid = xr.start + half_span;
    const ys = ds.data['y'];
    const new_mid = ds.data['x'].find((x, idx) => x > mid && ys[idx] === %s);
    if (new_mid !== undefined) {
        xr.start = new_mid - half_span;
        xr.end = new_mid + half_span;
    }
""" % TARGET_Y))
```

Comment: any thoughts about this error "W-1004 (BOTH_CHILD_AND_ROOT): Models should not be a document root if they are in a layout box:"

Comment: @Victor Looks like you do something like `curdoc().add_root(row(p, b)); curdoc().add_root(p)`. Apart from this guess, it's hard to say without the code.

Comment: Yes, that is right. On the other hand, I actually tried to figure out ‘previous 2’ just like ‘next 2’ thing never worked. Is there a  reason behind that ?

Comment: @Victor There definitely is a reason, but I'm not a clairvoyant. If you tried to implement it by using `ds.data['x'].find`, that's the reason - you can't do it since `find` only searches forward, but you need to search backward, so you'll have to iterate manually with a `for` loop.